# Google Chrome not updating in Deepin Linux after release update to 20.9

Tags: chrome, software-updates, deepin, deepin-desktop-environment

After release updating Deepin Linux to 20.9 and if you have previously installed Goggle Chrome you'll notice it can no longer be updated (specifically to version 112.xxx).

Downloading and trying to install the usual .deb file from [Google](https://www.google.com/chrome/?brand=FNES&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8qaYzcm-_gIVwQYGAB2olwtsEAAYASAAEgKaFPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) with the installer app results in a dependencies error. (Re-)adding the repository doesn't allow updates either.

Google Chrome keeps complaining, correctly, about being outdated and suggests updating but clicking the message only opens the link above to download yhe installer.

How can we update Google Chrome in the new Linux Deepin 20.9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to force install the new .deb from Google.

1. Download it from the usual website (mentioned in the question)
2. Open the Terminal in the directory where you downloaded the installer
3. Run `sudo apt install --reinstall ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

This install the current Google Chrome version (112.0.5615.165), (re-)installs the Google Chrome repository and will keep Google Chrome updated from now on.